# The way to write an adress

Tags: meaning

Which sentence would be better while writing the adress of my house ?

> My house is two house beside the the green buiding.
>
> My house is the second house beside the green building

Comment: Those aren't addresses. Possibly the second would work as a description of the location of your house, although it does not say whether your house is on the left or the right of the green building.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't an address, it's a description of how to find your house.

We say that a house is *next door to* the ones nearest to it, not *beside.* The expression for other buildings a little further away is *[so many] doors from*, so you could say

"My house is two doors from the green building."

Comment: Also *"two doors down from..."* or *"two doors up from..."* depending on the direction of travel.

Comment: Or _"next door but one"_.